# Link application with database

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, npm-scripts

I'm trying to link up my application with my database using the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) library. Here's my code:

```
//Require Libraries
const mysql  = require('mysql');

//Set up MySql connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host       : "255.255.255.255", //that ain't actually the ip :P
  port       : "3306",
  user       : "root",
  password   : "password :P",
  database   : "db_name"
});

connection.connect(); //Connect to the database
```

The error the code gives is:

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED (MY IP IS IN THIS BIT):3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1047:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1150:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\file\location:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\file\location\Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\file\location\Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\file\location\index.js:25:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
```

If you are wondering, the database is most certainly running, I can connect to it using mySQL workbench. Also just a quick note that the database is being hosted remotely just in case that may change anything.

Comment: try connecting to a local instance, if it works then it's obviously not your code. You will have to find out the issue is on the remote host. If you don't have a backup of the remote server, troubleshoot what you can locally.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the MySQL workbench->Server->Users_and_Privileges if your user connecting to the remote database is allowed to do that from your "host". See also [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html) for more information.

Comment: I've just checked, the user is allowed from my host. I have also just tried to make a new user that can only connect from my IP to see if that would work but still nothing.